# Run one .py file from another .py file

Tags: python-3.x

I have created a program that calculates size of files. I have created another program that sends mail to user. Name of programs is filesize.py and mailsend.py respectively. The mailsend.py is working perfectly, when I run it, I can see mail in my gmail inbox. But I want to run this mailsend.py from code of filesize.py.

I have done this in filesize.py: ( I am sure what I am trying to do is foolish, but I am new to programming let alone python )

```
import mailsend.py
cmd="python mailsend.py"
os.system(cmd)
```

And this is not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Replace `import mailsend.py` to `import os`.

More recommended way is...

**mailsend.py**

```
def main():
    # Put old `mailsend.py` content here.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**filesize.py**

```
import mailsend
mailsend.main()
```

Comment: Thanks. For importing mailsend, both files should be in same folder?

Comment: @abhishekverma, Anywhere in `sys.path`.